# Laravel echo server with socket.io show 404 blocked by CORS

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, socket.io, laravel-echo

i'm trying to utilize laravel echo server combined with socket.io for my chat apps. But it shows an error that said
[image]

When i'm trying at my local device, the server is working fine, it can trigger and listen. But when i host on my vps at AWS EC2 service, it shows some error like i mentioned above. I've been stuck for 2 days already not knowing how to solve it. I'm using ubuntu 20.04, web server nginx, npm laravel-echo-server 1.6.2 and socket.io for client version 2.4. i already allow port that i'm using on my server

[image]

Here is my laravel-echo-server.json

```
{
"authHost": "https://domain",
"authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
"clients": [],
"database": "redis",
"databaseConfig": {
    "redis": {
        "redis": {
            "host":"127.0.0.1",
            "port":"6379"
        }
    },
    "sqlite": {
        "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
    }
},
"devMode": true,
"host": null,
"port": "6002",
"protocol": "http",
"socketio": {},
"secureOptions": 67108864,
"sslCertPath": "",
"sslKeyPath": "",
"sslCertChainPath": "",
"sslPassphrase": "",
"subscribers": {
    "http": false,
    "redis": true
},
"apiOriginAllow": {
    "allowCors": true,
    "allowOrigin": "https:domain, http://localhost:8080",
    "allowMethods": "GET, POST",
    "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
}
```

}

And here is my server block configuration

```
server {
server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
root /var/www/domain/public;

index index.html index.htm index.php;

location / {
  # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
 }

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}


listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot}

server {
if ($host = www.domain.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


if ($host = domain.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
return 404; # managed by Certbot  

location /socket.io/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:6002/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
}
```

Here is my client code

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: "socket.io",
  host: "https://back-lms.gamifindo.com:6002",
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution! Its on server block configuration all along. I moved this code to the upper of my server bracket tag, then it just works!

```
location /socket.io/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:6002/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
}
```